# Render Google Recaptcha Without Callback

Tags: javascript, recaptcha

I want to render the recaptcha element without the onload callback. I have a page that has no `<form>`. They use jquery to get the value from the input field before saving to database so I want to get a response before saving.

HTML head:

```
<script src='https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js'></script>
```

BODY:

```
<div id="googleQuoteRecapture"></div>
```

JS inside document.ready:

```
var widget = document.getElementById('googleQuoteRecapture')
var widgetId1 = grecaptcha.render(widget, {
  'sitekey' : 'site_key',
  'theme' : 'light'
});
```

> Uncaught ReferenceError: grecaptcha is not defined

The aim is to `grecaptcha.getResponse(widgetId1)`

Is this possible?

Comment: Where are you defining `grecaptcha`?

Comment: @TheIncorrigible1 I thought loading the script in the head would define it?

Comment: I don't see it defined in the api you're linking in at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use an interval to check for the presence of the `grecaptcha` variable.

Here is an example:

```js
var interval = setInterval(function(){
  if(window.grecaptcha){
    var widget = document.getElementById('googleQuoteRecapture')
    var widgetId1 = grecaptcha.render(widget, {
      'sitekey' : 'site_key',
      'theme' : 'light'
    });
    clearInterval(interval);
  }
}, 100);
```

But is much easer to use the `onloadCallback` parameter.

Comment: ahhh `window`. Cool

Comment: YOU ARE AWESOME, SAVED MY LIFE :)